# Not Showing Background Image in html page?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am new to html i trying to add background image of body below code i tried

```
<!doctype html >
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> learning html</title>

            <style> 
                body{
                    background-image: url("C:\Users\vs\Downloads\html\VnoRpdq.gif");
                    }
            </style>

        </head>
        <body>
            <h1> This Home Page</h1>
            <h2>ADDED BACKGROUND</h2>
        </body>
    </html>
```

path name and file name and extension of image is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change it to have `file:///` protocol:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title> learning html</title>

            <style> 
                body{
                    background-image: url("file:///C:\Users\vs\Downloads\html\VnoRpdq.gif");
                    }
            </style>

        </head>
        <body>
            <h1> This Home Page</h1>
            <h2>ADDED BACKGROUND</h2>
        </body>
    </html>
```